# Unable to addShard in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sharding, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to deploy mongodb sharding. I have deployed a replica set in three machines. However, I still can't seem to make it work when I try to `sh.addShard("test/mongodb1.example.net:27017")` to all the three nodes. The error shown is:

```
2016-11-09T16:02:46.704+0800 W NETWORK  [conn105] No primary detected for set team3
```

Another error:

```
{
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "could not find host matching read preference { mode: \"primary\" } for set test",
  "code" : 133
}
```

1) Set up initial replica set for each node (This works fine)

a) Run these for all 3 nodes:

```
mkdir /temp/data/team3
./mongod --replSet "team3" --dbpath /temp/data/team3
./mongo --host <mongodb[x].example.net>
```

b) Primary node runs:

```
rs.initiate()
rs.add("mongodb2.example.net")
rs.add("mongodb3.example.net")
```

2) Setting up configuration server and query router for Three replica cluster (This works fine)

Primary node runs:

```
mkdir /temp/data/config_rs
./mongod --configsvr --replSet "config_rs" --dbpath /temp/data/config_rs
./mongo --host mongodb1.example.net --port 27019
```

3) Add shards (Problem with adding shard)

Primary node runs:

```
sh.addShard("mongodb1.example.net")
sh.addShard("mongodb2.example.net")
sh.addShard("mongodb3.example.net")
```

Comment: Have you double-checked the replicaset configuration and status before you start adding shards?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer.. Problem is that you must give those sh.addShard commands thru mongoS service. So you don't connect to primary with mongo command, you **must** connect to mongos service.

So, first you must start mongos to some machine, f.ex. one (or all) config servers are good candidates.

[Mongos documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/)

[Step by step to sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)